# Deletion of codons at the start of a sequence in preparation for heterogeneous expression. Why?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics

I am reading a patent where they isolate a gene from cDNA constructed from RNA extracted from plant matter.

The subsequent step (in preparation for heterogeneous expression in E Coli.) puzzles me: 
[image]

The codon optimization I can understand but this part confuses me "...remove the first 23 codons from the DNA sequence and replace [the start?] by the ATGGCT sequence."

Why would one remove a set of codons at the start of a sequence? How did they decide how many to remove Is there an obvious reason I am missing?  Also what is special about the ATGGCT sequence.

Any ideas why they would do this?

The start of the new sequence (1650 bp) looks like this:

```
atggctaccg ataatgacag ctctgaaaac cgtcgtatgg gtaattacaa gccgtccatc       60

tggaactacg acttcctgca gtccctggct acccgccaca atatcatgga agagcgccac      120
```

whereas the original sequence (1710 bp) was this:

```
atggattctt ccaccgccac cgccatgaga gctccattca ttgatcatac tgatcatgtg       60

aatctcagaa ctgataacga ttcctcagag aatcgaagga tggggaatta taaacccagt      120
```

Another point I am confused about is that 1710 - 23 x 3 + 6 is 1647. But the new seq. is 1650 bp. What gives?

Comment: Obvious reasons would be: a signal peptide, nope, doesn't look like one, annoying restriction sites, nah, not the case either

Comment: Proteolytic cleavage and N-end rule

Comment: @Ashafix Can you elaborate more on that? How is the N-end rule applicable in this case? If I translate both those sequences the first Amino Acid is Met. So no stabilizing residue seems to have been added.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer would be to ask the authors of the patent. 
Several other possibilities (see comments) were excluded, such as:

- restriction sites which interfere with cloning
- signal peptide
- proteolytic cleavage

Although it's just a theory, removing part of the N-terminus might improve protein stability and half-life time because the first 30-40 amino acids lack an ordered structure (as judged by submitting the structure to [Phyre](http://www.sbg.bio.ic.ac.uk/phyre2/html/page.cgi?id=index)). Those structures are known to aggregate and influence protein stability.

References:

[The use of systematic N- and C-terminal deletions to promote production and structural studies of recombinant proteins.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18171622?dopt=Abstract)

[Sequence composition of disordered regions fine-tunes protein half-life](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4351145/)

[Production of prone-to-aggregate proteins](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0014579313008144)